# Yarn vs Npm - "works on my machine" - clarification?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I'm new to yarn and something caught my eyes while reading [*this article*](https://scotch.io/@brian_kimo/npm-vs-yarn) which states :

> Deterministic:
> The same dependencies will be installed the same exact
> way across every machine regardless of install order. Yarn resolves
> *"works on my machine"* issues around versioning and non-determinism by
> using lockfiles and an install algorithm that is deterministic and
> reliable

**Question:**

I don't understand : When I write `npm install` it looks at the `package.json` and installs the exact version and each version also installed its dependencies according to its own `package.json` and so on and so on

So what's the difference (regarding this aspect)

An example of scenario for "*thing that can go wrong in npm while not in yarn*" will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package.json file often contains the minimum version required of a dependency. For instance, you could have "^1.0.0", which matches with version 1.0.0 or any minor releases.

`{
  "name": "my_package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "my_dep": "^1.0.0"
  }
}`

When you run npm install, it could install the version 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.0 etc of "my_dep", because all those versions meet the requirements of package.json. You could end up with version 1.0.0 on your local machine and 1.1.0 on your test environment.

Yarn creates a yarn.lock file automatically to make sure you always install the same version of "my_dep". It generates something like this:

```
# THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
# yarn lockfile v1
my_dep@^1.0.0:    
version "1.1.0"
resolved "https://registry.npmjs.org/my_dep/-/my_dep-1.1.0.tgz#a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3n4o5p6q7r8s9t0"
```

Yarn will use this file to resolve "my_dep" to version 1.1.0, even if there is a new version (1.2.0) available.

> All yarn.lock files should be checked into source control (e.g. git or mercurial). This allows Yarn to install the same exact dependency tree across all machines, whether it be your coworker’s laptop or a CI server.

References:

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning

https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/yarn-lock

Comment: I believe `package-lock.json` does the same job for `npm install`.

Comment: @Devmonster  
IMHO npm install will install the exact version unless you do npm update where now it minds ~ or ^.... no ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, but I can imagine some scenarios where you can end up with different versions in different environments. If you run `npm update` on your local machine without the option `--save`, the updated version won't be recorded in your package.json, therefore your local version will be updated, but not on your testing environment

Comment: Unlike what @DevMonster claims, `npm` has the same feature. based on NPM's official documentation, `package-lock.json` describes a single representation of a dependency tree such that teammates, deployments, and continuous integration are guaranteed to install exactly the same dependencies. https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json